# org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context

Tags: tomcat, intellij-plugin, tomcat9

I am using smart tomcat to deploy my web app , My app has 2 portal I am trying to run 8081 and 1 on 8080. I want to run both the configuration parallelly(portal200 and portal300) and I know this setup works , and I have running it for long..However when I am running either of them and then try to run another parallelly, the first one get undeploy and stops , also I start getting logs of the second one both console(e.g. if I run portal200 and then I start portal300 , the portal200 will give error Undeploying context and console logs of portal300 will start showing on portal200's console), first I thought this should be admin port issue, but it is not , I tried restarting the IDE and unstall/install plugin(tomcat), rebuilding my project. I am attaching screen shots of my configuration.. please suggest any idea, what could be the issue.
ss:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like higher version smart tomcat does not support multiple instances , after downgrading the smart tomcat plugin version , It is working fine